# Merging nodes with the same name to a single node

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

i have an `Xml` that contains two `Nodes` with the same name `Settings` as following

```
<TransSettings>
  <Settings>
    <Force>False</Force>
  </Settings>
  <Settings>
    <Active>True</Active>
  </Settings>
</TransSettings>
```

i want to merge these two `Nodes` into one single `Node`

```
<TransSettings>
  <Setting>
    <Force>False</Force>
    <Active>True</Active>
  </Setting>
</TransSettings>
```

Note that the parent `Node` might contain more than two `Settings`

Comment: XML contains only these two Settings nodes? What if contains multiple Settings nodes?

Comment: If you have to just do this with text-files in a stand-alone programm, you can do this with Python very easy.

Comment: @RohitVats yes it could contain more than one

Comment: @user1767754 i don't have much experience with `Python` besides it's a whole process i can't separate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename); // or XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var elems = xDoc.Descendants("Settings").SelectMany(x => x.Elements()).ToList();
xDoc.Root.RemoveAll();
xDoc.Root.Add(new XElement("Settings", elems));
var newxml = xDoc.ToString();
```

OUTPUT:

```
<TransSettings>
  <Settings>
    <Force>False</Force>
    <Active>True</Active>
  </Settings>
</TransSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");
var transElement = xDoc.Descendants("TransSettings").FirstOrDefault();

if (transElement != null)
{
     var settings = transElement.Descendants("Settings");
     List<XElement> settingElements = new List<XElement>();
     for(int i=0;i<settings.Count;i++)
     {
         settingElements.AddRange(settings[i].Elements());
         settings[i].Remove();
     }
     XElement elem = new XElement("Setting", settingElements);
     transElement.Add(elem);
     xDoc.Save("path");
}
```

Comment: this wroks too but it needs some corrections: `for (int i=0; i < settings.Count(); i++)`, `settingElements.AddRange(settings.ElementAt(i).Elements());` and `settings.ElementAt(i).Remove();`